# Quarkus dependencies debug

Tags: quarkus

Is it possible to debug a dependency jar/source (imported by maven) using InteliJ in a Quakus application?

My break points aren't being reached even though they are active.

Thanks

The break point is active, however not reached...
[image]

Comment: This image shows that break point is enabled but it isn't active (never will spuspend any thread). Are you sure your application is running in debug mode? From now I don't think it's a Quarkus related issue.